# Can the same nested serializer be used to output different data - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

If I have something like this:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('url', 'owner', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snippets = SnippetSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'snippets')
```

Then it will output all the fields defined in the SnippetSerializer. But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
snippets = SnippetSerializer(fields=('title', 'code'))
```

without having to do a duplicated SnippetSerializer like so:

```
class SnippetSerializerSmall(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('title', 'code')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some new documentation on dynamically modifying serializer fields that's just gone up on the site today...

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#dynamically-modifiying-fields

#### Quoting the docs verbatim here...

Once a serializer has been initialized, the dictionary of fields that are set on the serializer may be accessed using the `.fields` attribute.  Accessing and modifying this attribute allows you to dynamically modify the serializer.

#### Example

For example, if you wanted to be able to set which fields should be used by a serializer at the point of initializing it, you could create a serializer class like so:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instatiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

This would then allow you to do the following:

```
>>> class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
>>>     class Meta:
>>>         model = User
>>>         fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
>>>
>>> print UserSerializer(user)
{'id': 2, 'username': 'jonwatts', 'email': 'jon@example.com'}
>>>
>>> print UserSerializer(user, fields=('id', 'email'))
{'id': 2, 'email': 'jon@example.com'}
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify fields for a nested serializer?